# Configuration Issue In Spring MVC setup

Tags: java, spring-mvc, configuration

I am setting a project for Spring MVC but it seems to hold some issue.
while configuring I am Tomcat-7 and JRE 1.8 but due to this project is not setting up.

Earlier when I was learning Spring Core JRE 1.8 was not an issue it was automatically getting configured. But now while building MVC project it is generating below problem, it say's 
***"Faceted Project problem(Java Version Mismatch)"***

and is this happening when i am not using this **Apache Tomcatv7 is being loaded along with JRE1.7**
[1: this image I have manually changed the JRE1.8]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JNEoP8_Yb79-2dGGFm3EaZKI5uHjj5RB

[2: But still on selecting Apache Tomcat JRE1.7 is being loaded]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SVlL1h7rF9kspYNnUe70O5Y3NYalBtQ2

I therefore want to use JRE1.8 for configuring the project, but it seems Apache Tomcat version is Generating problem.

> ***So do I need to upgrade the version of Tomcat??***

Answer (score 0):

For your first statement :

> In [offcial page of Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) it says that Tomcat 7.x is compatible
>   with JDK-6 and higher version of JDK. So JDK 8 should not give an
>   issue with it.

I think the main reason could be, different versions of Java in compiler and in project facets. The Java facet version needs to always match the java compiler compliance level.

If you want to use Java compiler level as 1.8, **then you should upgrade tomcat runtime envionment to java 8** and also change the project facets to 1.8.

Java 7 at the runtime and java 8 at compile time, this combination will not work. this would be worked for vice versa.

You can change Java runtime as follows :

```
1. select Apache> Tomcat 7 Server
2. Configure Runtime Environments
3. On this screen there is a pulldown labeled JREs.
4. You should find your JRE listed. If not use the Installed JRE button.
5. Select the desired JRE. Click the FINISH button.
```

Hope this solves your problem. Do upvote if this has helped a tiny bit :)